# Writing to file in background using PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, output

A bit new to all this, but I'm trying to display a webpage while a file is written to disk on the server in the background. I let a simple page load and then send an AJAX response to a second script, which handles the actual file operations. I do this so that the user isn't waiting 30+ seconds for a simple page to load while the file is generated, as well as trying to avoid a browser timeout. Once the file is written, I'd like to redirect to it. However, the file never gets created and the redirect sends you straight to a 404, despite the AJAX request always returning a successful status code.

**Example**

**`index.php`**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $.ajax({
        url: "out.php",
        method: "get",
        data: { 'answer' : 42 },
        success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
          alert(jqxhr.responseText);
          $("body").append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;out.log'>");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`out.php`**

```
<?php
  echo "WHAT IS HAPPENING....";
  $fd = fopen("out.log", "wb");
  fwrite($fd, "Not this... " . $_GET['answer']);
  fclose($fd);
?>
```

`out.php` works as I expect it to if I run it using `php-cgi out.php answer=42`, but again, when accessed through a browser, nothing gets written.

Is there any way to get `out.php` to create and write to `out.log`?

Comment: If you put on your browser localhost/your_project/out.php?answer=42, does something??

Comment: Yikes, don't know why I didn't think to try that... No, it does not write a file. Beginning to think it has something to do with permissions (currently the directory and files are not owned by apache.apache). However, I've been able to write things to disk in the past without those permissions using output buffering. I'll give   that a shot and then report back.

Comment: Permissions...are you on a Linux style environment??...i miss that too XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I simply didn't have the permissions to write files in the directory I was attempting to use... Everything's working for me now after a little `chown` magic.